# Can you find and remove unused notebooks from JupyterHub?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I'm a new engineer on a mostly scientist team running data pipelines.  There are a ton of stale and unused notebooks sitting around and I'd like to remove code which hasn't run in a while from our codebase.  What options do I have of figuring this out without manually going through each one and asking the team?

I've looked around documentation and can't find much.